# i m using a POS Tagger with this code

Tags: eclipse, pos-tagger

I'm using a POS Tagger with eclipse, here is code

```java
package tagger;

import java.io.*; 
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger; 

public class ab_web 
{   
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger( " D:\\tagger\\english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");
    String sample = "i go to school by bus";
    String tagged = tagger.tagString(sample);
    System.out.println(tagged);
   }
}
```

but I am having exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at tagger.ab_web.main(ab_web.java:8)
```

kindly tell me any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

`Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` means that the `MaxentTagger` class you are trying to use was compiled using Java 8 but you are trying to run it using an earlier version of Java.

Look in the Eclipse 'Run > Run Configurations' menu and find your program. Make sure the 'Java Runtime Environment' is set to use Java 8 (or JavaSE-1.8').

If no Java 8 is listed in the Run Configuration you may have to tell Eclipse about the location of a Java 8 JRE. Open the Eclipse Preferences and go to 'Java > Installed JREs' to do this.

You must be running Eclipse Mars or Luna to get full Java 8 support.